# What are the Limitations for Connecting to an Access Query in Excel

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access, ms-access-2007, union-all

I have an Access 2007 database that has a number of tables, some are fairly large (100,000+ records); I have created a `union query` to pull some of the same types of data from multiple tables into one large query for pivot table manipulation and reporting.  For example:

```
SELECT Language
FROM Table1
UNION ALL SELECT Language
FROM Table2
UNION ALL SELECT Language
FROM Table3;
```

This works.  I found, quickly, however, that a `union query` will not show up when connecting to the datasource from Excel 2007.  So, I created a second query to reference the `union query`.  Like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM [The Above Union Query];
```

This query works and it, initially, was accessible from Excel.  Time passed, I've added more data.  Suddenly, when I connect to my Access database from Excel my query referencing the union has disappeared.  MS Access shows no signs of an issue (data displays in Access) and my other non-union queries are showing up in Excel 2007 ... but not the one that references the union.

#### What could be going on?  Why did it disappear?

I noticed if I switch some of the referenced tables in the `union query` to a smaller table (with less rows) all of sudden the query appears in Excel again.  At least, I think that's what the difference is.  I really can't put my finger on why some of the `union queries` won't show up and some will.

Am stumped and need some guidance.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What if you did a Make Table Query on your Union Query instead of a Select Query. Then just had Excel reference the new table? That would at least tell you if you are exceeding a row limitation in Excel, but that seems unlikely since all reports are that they have dramatically increased the row limitation in Excel 2007 over Excel 2003. You could even write a macro in Excel to tell Access to run the Make Table before getting the data.